# Using the push function to append a list to the default-frame-alist variable

Tags: major-mode, gui-emacs, menu-bar, alists

I've noticed some people use this to disable the menu bar in the GUI:

```
(push '(menu-bar-lines . 0) default-frame-alist)
```

and some people use this:

```
(menu-bar-mode -1)
```

Both achieve the same. The first seems to append a list `'(menu-bar-lines . 0)` to the `default-frame-alist` variable.

I was wondering which approach is better to use. The first or the second one? or it doesn't matter.

Comment: The main problem with push is that it doesn't check that whatever it pushes is not already on the list (or whether it conflicts with something on the list). If you are sure that that's not the case, go ahead and push. OTOH, calling `menu-bar-mode` is safer precisely because it checks such things. And it may be the case that even if you push a duplicate (or conflicting) entry, nothing bad happens. The question is: how comfortable are you taking that risk - and that's a question only you can answer. What @lawlist's answer provides is a best practice: you can follow it - or not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`push` prepends, rather than appends.  `push` should *not* be used in this context because it does not remove or replace an existing element of the `default-frame-alist` with the parameter `menu-bar-lines`.  Type `M-x find-function RET menu-bar-mode RET` to see how `menu-bar-mode` works when activated and deactivated.  Use `(menu-bar-mode -1)` to deactivate.

Comment: Thank you. What if I decide to maximize the Emacs frame during startup with `(push '(fullscreen . maximized) default-frame-alist)` can the `push` be used in that situation?

Comment: I have these in `early-init.el`. I can set it with `(set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'maximized)` but I still don't know if it's the proper way of doing it.

Comment: Thank you. You helped me a lot. I set the frame value to `nil` in `(set-frame-parameter nil 'fullscreen 'maximized)` and I'm not sure if it's good or not. Even though it seems to me that all new frames are in full-screen which is what I want.

Comment: I created the `early-init-file` at `~/.emacs.d/early-init.el` and placed the following snippet at the top of the file:  `(message "%s | %s" (selected-frame) default-frame-alist)`.  Then, I launched Emacs 28.2 and checked the `*Messages*` buffer and saw that the `default-frame-alist` has a `nil` value at this particular stage of the startup process.  Because there is no pre-existing element containing the `fullscreen` parameter, I determined that it is now safe to use `push`.  E.g., `(push '(fullscreen . maximized) default-frame-alist)`.  `set-frame-parameter` is used for a particular frame.

Comment: then `push` is okay with `menu-bar-lines` as well when inside `early-init.el`. Right?

Comment: If we place a message at the top of the `early-init-file` like so:  `(message "menu-bar-mode:  %s" menu-bar-mode)` and launch Emacs 28.2, we see that `menu-bar-mode` is already activated at this point in the startup process.  While it is true that `push` may be used to add the element `(menu-bar-lines . 0)` to the `default-frame-alist` at this juncture, that still leaves the variable `menu-bar-mode` set to `t`.  Having that variable remain with a non-nil value will not affect the `default-frame-alist`, but it seems a little cleaner to me by turning off that global minor-mode.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I will go with `(menu-bar-mode -1)`, `(tool-bar-mode -1)`, and `(scroll-bar-mode -1)` then.